# Ускорить вывод большой строковой переменной в консоль - Java SE

Tags: java, оптимизация, консоль, производительность

Друзья, помогите, кто чем сможет, пожалуйста. Необходимо вывести 10 млн записей(Имя, адрес, телефон) в консоль.
Я делаю так: создаю переменную StringBuffer, заполняю её 10 млн записей, и вывожу посредством System.out.println(). Без наворотов и магии, просто обычный вывод в консоль. Он займёт, по моим подсчётам, 16 минут. Это очень долго.
Помогите разобраться. Может какие-то фичи есть.

Comment: можете интерес удовлетворить, зачем вам это? в консоль все равно не поместиться (на винде), так что проще просто вывести последние 2-5к записей

Comment: @Виктор, стажировка в компании. Это задание...
Условия: вывод 10 млн записей в консоль. Ограничение - быстрота.
Вот и маюсь.

Comment: как минимум замените StringBuffer на StringBuilder

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович, разницы не заметил)

Comment: ну это странно ,  StringBuilder должен работать быстрее... без кода сложно посоветовать, что делать. я бы на вашем месте измерил время выполнения разных частей кода. сколько читается файл, сколько работает билдер, сколько выводит в консоль. исходя из этого я бы думал, как выводить...

Answer (score 1):

> `println` is not slow, it's the underlying `PrintStream` that is
>   connected with the console, provided by the hosting operating system.
>
> You can check it yourself: compare dumping a large text file to the
>   console with piping the same textfile into another file:
>
> ```
> cat largeTextFile.txt
> cat largeTextFile.txt > temp.txt
> ```
>
> Reading and writing are similiar and proportional to the size of the
>   file `(O(n))`, the only difference is, that the destination is
>   different (console compared to file). And that's basically the same
>   with `System.out`.
>
> The underlying OS operation (displaying chars on a console window) is
>   slow because
>
> The bytes have to be sent to the console application (should be quite
>   fast) Each char has to be rendered using (usually) a true type font
>   (that's pretty slow, switching off anti aliasing could improve
>   performance, btw) The displayed area may have to be scrolled in order
>   to append a new line to the visible area (best case: bit block
>   transfer operation, worst case: re-rendering of the complete text
>   area)

---

`println` не медленный, это базовый `PrintStream`, который связан с консолью, предоставляемой операционной системой хостинга.

Вы можете проверить это самостоятельно: сравнить демпинг большого текстового файла с консолью с тем же самым текстовым файлом в другой файл:

```
cat largeTextFile.txt 
cat largeTextFile.txt> temp.txt
```

Чтение и запись аналогичны и пропорциональны размеру файла `(O (n))`, единственное отличие в том, что назначение отличается (консоль по сравнению с файлом). И это в основном то же самое с `System.out`.

Операция операционной системы (отображение символов в окне консоли) происходит медленно, потому что байты должны быть отправлены в консольное приложение (должно быть довольно быстро). Каждый символ должен отображаться с использованием (обычно) шрифта истинного типа (это довольно медленно, выключение сглаживания может повысить производительность, кстати).
Отображаемая область, возможно, придется прокручивать, чтобы добавить новую строку в видимую область (лучший случай: операция передачи бит-бит, худший случай: повторный рендеринг полной текстовой области).

---

Оригинал с другими ответами:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437715/why-is-system-out-println-so-slow

Comment: То есть программа прокручивает окно вывода, для возможности отображения переменной и это ухудшает производительность?
бит-бит, значит по частям?

Comment: программе для вывода текста в консоль приходиться его рисовать. Т.е. помимо чтения и создания строки все отправляется ОС для отрисовки на экран.

Comment: С этим понятно, спасибо!
Но, я извиняюсь, что отнимаю у вас время своими вопросами,что на счёт бит-бит. Я, честно признаться, не совсем въехал как же решить мою проблему.

Comment: Написать свою ОС, т.к. java передает ей данные, которые надо вывести на экран, а ОС уже этим занимается. (но это не точно, просто догадка)

Comment: А Вы откуда данные берете? Т.е. вывод строк Вы начинаете не сразу с получением первой информации - а только когда последнюю строку считаете которую вывести надо?